# Converting array of pointers to double pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am able to do this:

```
char * months[] = {"empty","jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"};

unsigned short int month_index = 4;
printf("The %dth month of the year is \"%s\".\n", month_index, months[month_index]);
```

But if I try and use a double pointer:

```
char ** months = {...};
```

It fails to build with a `excess elements in scalar initializer`. What does that mean exactly, and how would I initialize the above using a pointer to pointers?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Type Controls Everything**

```
char *months[] = {"empty","jan",...};
```

Declares months as an *array-of-pointers* to `char` where the initializer **completes the type** providing the number of pointers in the **array** (the "How many?" information) and initializing each pointer to point to the beginning of a valid character string. The complete type is `char *[13]` (an array of 13 pointers.

If you simply tried to declare:

```
char *months[];
```

You compiler would throw an error complaining that `months` was in *incomplete* type.

After `months` has been declared and initialized, then by operation of [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3), on access, months is type-compatible with `char**` as the first level of indirection is converted to a pointer to the first element, resulting in months being `char**` on access (subject to the 4 exceptions in the rule).

**Why Can't I Just Declare `char **months = {"empty","jan",...};` To Begin With?**

With a *pointer-to-pointer-to-type* there is no **array** involved at all. How many pointers are declared? While with `char *months[]...` the initializer *for the array* can complete the type and provide for the number of elements in an **array**, with `char **months`, you simply have a (pointer)-to-pointer with NO array involved at all. Meaning following the declarations of:

```
char **months;
```

`months` is simply an **uninitialized pointer** holding some indeterminate address. Any attempt to change the content of the indeterminate memory location results in *Undefined Behavior* (and likely a SegFault). The C-standard simply does not provide for initialization of a pointer-to-pointer as it does for an *Array*. [C11 Standard - 6.7.9 Initialization](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9)

> It fails to build with a `excess elements in scalar initializer`. What
>   does that mean exactly, and how would I initialize the above using a
>   pointer to pointers?

The error, while a bit subtle, makes perfect sense. You have a single pointer when you declare:

```
char **months;
```

If you try to initialize the single pointer with an initializer-list, e.g.

```
char **months = { "empty", "jan", "feb", ... };
```

There a are whole lot more than 1 excess element in the *initializer*...

You have two ways to initialize a pointer-to-pointer-to-type. (1) You can either allocate the number of pointers you need, e.g.

```
char **months = malloc (13 * sizeof *months);  /* allocate 13 pointers */
```

and then allocate for, or assign, a valid address to the first character in a character string to each of the 13-pointers, e.g. `months[0] = "empty"; months[1] = "jan", ...`; or

(2) you can assign the valid address of a (single) object that is type-compatible with your pointer, e.g.

```
char **my_months = months;
```

You can then access each individual string with `my_months[0]`, because the pointer-to-pointer now points to valid storage and the type is complete such that `my_months + 1` points to the next string after the current. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char *months[] = { "empty", "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", 
                        "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec" };
    char **my_months = months;
    size_t n = sizeof months / sizeof *months;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("my_months[%2zu] : %s\n", i, my_months[i]);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/my_months
my_months[ 0] : empty
my_months[ 1] : jan
my_months[ 2] : feb
my_months[ 3] : mar
my_months[ 4] : apr
my_months[ 5] : may
my_months[ 6] : jun
my_months[ 7] : jul
my_months[ 8] : aug
my_months[ 9] : sep
my_months[10] : oct
my_months[11] : nov
my_months[12] : dec
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This is a great explanation, makes things much clearer.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate iterating each letter of each string with the double pointer, if possible? I struggle with the canonical way to do this in C. Thanks!

Comment: @Yifangt sure. Since `month[i]` is a pointer to a string, adding another `[ ]` operation (which acts as a dereference and offset) allows to to iterate each character. For the example above `for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) { for (int j = 0; months[i][j]; j++) { putchar (months[i][j]); } putchar ('\n'); }` will iterate over each month writing a character at a time to `stdout` and writing a newline between each month. You can also use pointer notation if you like, (e.g. `putchar (*(months[i] + j));`

Comment: @Yifangt - here is the same example with [Iteration by Index and by Pointer](https://paste.opensuse.org/71aa2315306f) that you can compare the different methods with. Remember, on access, an array is converted to a pointer to its first element. Since `months` is an *array-of-pointers-to* `char`, on access the array is converted to a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `char` (e.g. `char **my_months`) pointing to the first word in the array. Dereferencing again (e.g. `my_months[i]`) simply gives *pointer-to* `char` and a final dererence give access to the `char` (e.g. `my_months[i][j]`)

Comment: You can fix the last heading. should be `puts ("\nCharacter at a time declaring another pointer\n");`. The link above expires Fri 05 Jan 2024 01:17:08 PM CST

Comment: @David Thanks a lot! I am always so confused with `my_months[i]` and `*(my_months + i)`, then `*(*(my_months + i) + j)` to print each letter, although I know they are pointer/address related. Need to find the right way to dissect this de-reference.

Comment: Take it one step at a time. Start with a 1D array `char arr[] =  "fire";` `arr` has type `char[5]` and per [§6.3.2.1(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) on access is a *pointer-to*  `char` (the first element is `'f'`, so it is a *pointer-to* `'f'`). To access the value at the address held by a pointer, you dereference the pointer, e.g. `*arr` provides access to `'f'`. Now `*arr` is actually `*(a + 0)` or `a[0]` where `0` is the offset from the base pointer address. You also see `arr[x]` is equivalent to `*(arr + x)`. Now a 2D array is just an *array-of-1D-arrays*

Comment: So in the case of `arr[x][y]` that is equivalent to `*(arr[x] + y)` or replacing the last array index with pointer notation is `*(*(arr + x) + y)`. Here a a couple of links that discuss pointer basics that may give you a easy way to wrap your head around it. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102) Also [How to handle a pointer to 2D array [2D array seg fault in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60498812/3422102)

Comment: Pay careful attention to the last link. There are some subtleties in type that are glossed over in the `months` example because you have any *array-of-pointers* to begin with, so there is no distinction in type between the *array-of-pointers* and *pointer-to-pointer* (it's all pointers). But if that were an *array-of* `int` or an *array-of* `struct` - then the first element is no longer a pointer and you can't simply convert from 2D array to pointer-to-pointer. (you will understand after reading the last link)

Answer (score 2):

I’m afraid what you wish to do is not possible.
This is not how C works, char ** and char * [n] are two different things when it comes to types, so you won’t be able to initialize a char ** with an entity of type char * [n].

The equivalent for your char** case would be:

```
char **x = (char *[]){"hello", "world"};
```

If you need this only for the initialization then keep it as it is using char * [n], it’s the right way to declare it.

You can always refer it as char ** anyway.

Comment: You are thinking right, but (1) with *"you won’t be able to initialize a char ** array"* -- there is no "array" involved; and (2) you CAN *"initialize a char ** [pointer] with an entity of type char * [n]"*. I know what you are trying to say, but someone trying to learn from what you are saying may be left a bit bewildered. You also need to explain what `(type){ initialization list }` is. A new programmer will have no idea what a *compound-literal* is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to assign array of pointers to double pointer, I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    char *arr[]={"hello","world"};
    char **ptr=arr;

    printf("%s\n",ptr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**
`world`