# Copy 2D array to new buffer with memcpy

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I want to copy an 2D array to a new 2D array within an internal buffer.

Let's suppose I have the following function:

```
uint8 the_2D_array[100][7];

void Get_2D_Array(uint8 **array)
{
   *array = &the_2D_array[0][0];   // Function which returns pointer to the first element of the 2D array
}
```

Later in my code I'm expecting to do something like this:

```
myBuffered_Aray[100][7];
uint8 *pValues;

Get_2D_Array(&pValues)
{
  for (uint8 i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  { 
     for (uint8 j = 0; j < 7; j++)
     {
        (void)memcpy(myBuffered_Aray[i][j], (u8_t*)&pValues[i][j], sizeof(uint8));
     }   
  }
```

}

The part with

```
(u8_t*)&pValues[i][j]
```

will not work because of "Expression must have pointer to object type".

How to do it correctly?

Comment: `uint8 **array` (a double-pointer) has NOTHING at all to do with an array. You want `uint8 (*array)[7]` as the parameter ( a *pointer-to-array* of `uint8 [7]`)

Comment: See: [2D array seg fault in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60498534/2d-array-seg-fault-in-c/60498812#60498812) for a further explanation. And you don't include `memcpy` in a loop to copy a 2D array, it is simply `memcpy (myBuffered_Array, array, 100 * 7 * sizeof (uint8))` -- no looping. (copying a single `uint8` at a time with `memcpy` in nested loops would make no sense -- you can simply use assignment for that).

Comment: If you provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), either myself or others can help with further details on  your exact situation.

Comment: The error is more likely pointing at the first parameter `myBuffered_Aray[i][j]`. Should be `&myBuffered_Aray[i][j]`. And just what is `u8_t` anyway? Copy paste the actual code.

Comment: And finally why do you do 700 memcpy calls instead of 1? That's very inefficient.

Comment: @ yes you are right. I totally misunderstood the concept of memcpy. Now I'm doing it with one memcpy