# C,GCC warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, initialization

```
char strings[10][100], ** ptr = strings;
```

Someone can help with it? What isn't right with this part of code, isn't right that **strings == strings[0][0], and strings[0][0] is char? Sorry for my really bad english.

Comment: Well, yes, `char (*)[100]` does not equate to `char **`. So `char strings[10][100], (*ptr)[100] = strings;`

Comment: Full explanation [2D array seg fault in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60498812/3422102)

Comment: Hint: There's a huge difference between `char *a[n]` and `char a[n][m]`. One is an array of pointers, the other is an array of arrays. A 2D array is allocated as a contiguous block, but an array of pointers to other arrays is usually *not*.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler recognizes that `strings` is an array of arrays and therefore suggests to declare the pointer accordingly:

```
char strings[10][100], (*ptr)[100] = strings;
```

### Update:

As mentioned by David C. Rankin a conversion takes place in the initialization of `ptr`. `strings` is converted from an *array of arrays of 100 chars* to a *pointer to an array of 100 chars* pointing to the first element of this array of arrays. The conversion is specified here: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3).

Comment: It would help to explain array conversion to a pointer and reference [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) as the source of the conversion.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for the link, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: But if I use this declaration i cant use this part of my code: (fgets(*(ptr + ct),99,stdin); //ct of int type. How I can fill all the lines of the array with such a declaration?

Comment: You can, `fgets (ptr[ct], 100, stdin)` is fine. Note, with `fgets()` you do not subtract 1, `fgets (ptr[ct], 100, stdin)` is correct. Where `0 <= ct < 10`

Comment: But in this case i get error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds.  I can fix it if i will do char (* ptr)[100] = strings; instead char (* ptr)[] = strings; But what i shoul to do if i don't know about size of my array(i use it in my function).

Answer (score 0):

the warning:

```
Warning: initialization of ‘char **’ from incompatible pointer type ‘char (*)[100]’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    8 |   char strings[10][100], ** ptr = strings;
```

It says that: ptr & strings are different types so ptr[0][0¿ & string[0][0] are diffrents

Comment: But string is array and array's name is pointer on first element. In my case string = =&string[0]; string[0] == &string[0][0] HENCE string == &&string[0][0] HENCE **string == string[0][0] HENCE type of string is char **. What is wrong with it?

Comment: To test your code I use:
`int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    char strings[10][100], **ptr = strings;
    printf("%s\n", strings);
    if (strings[0][0] == ptr[0][0])
        printf("Same");
    else
        printf("Not the same");
    return 0;
}`
Here: It prints Not the same
But if I change to 
`
`char strings[10][100], (*ptr)[100] = strings;`

It return Same because there are the same type