# About variable not a pointer printed through %p

Tags: c, pointers

I am a student who is studying pointer unit.

I posted this message to get a lesson from my seniors because I was ignorant and couldn't understand it well.

First of all, thank you so much for reading my article.

```
int main(){
int a;
int* pa;

pa = &a;
a = 1;

printf ("'a' something: %p\n", a);
printf ("'a' address : %p\n", &a);
printf ("'a' value : %d\n\n", a);

printf ("'pa' address value : %p\n", pa);
printf("'*pa' address value? : %p\n", *pa);


return 0;
}
```

result

'a' of what?: 0x1

'a' address: 0x7ffd407638b8

'a' value : 1

'pa' address : 0x7ffd407638b8

'*pa' address : 0x1

> **Here's the question.**

Question1. I would like to ask if the value printed through the %p format means something, **even though variable a is not a pointer.**

Question2. I would like to ask you if there is a **different** reason **why the result of printing the 'pa' through %p format and the result of printing '*pa' %p format even the same pointer called p.**

Question3. If I understood the above two questions, I don't need to ask about this.***why variable a is the same as the 'a' printed in the %p format and pointer '*pa' printed in the %p format.**

> Thank you.

Thank you so much for taking your time to read my article.

Comment: Printing a non-pointer with %p results in undefined behavior, and the results are formally unpredictable.

Comment: You're trying to print a memory address of a dereferenced pointer (in the last printf statement).

Comment: When you use `printf` (`fprintf`) the *conversion-specifier* much match the variable type you are trying to print or the behavior is undefined. [C11 Standard - 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function(p9)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9) "9  If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: If you are interested in a couple of answers that discuss pointer-basics in general, here are a few links that provide basic discussions of pointers that may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102). While the question titles discuss pointers-to-pointers and structs -- the answers, in part, discuss the basics of pointers. Good luck with your coding.

Comment: The type of the argument corresponding to the `%p` must be `void*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Question

> "I would like to ask if the value printed through the `%p` format means something, even though variable a is not a pointer."

It is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) to print a non-pointer value with `%p`. Strictly seen it is even not compliant to the standard, if you don't cast the pointer to `void *` as relative argument.

The C standard states (emphasize mine):

> "p **The argument shall be a pointer to void**. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner."
>
> Source: C18, 7.21.6.1/8

> "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.288) **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined**."
>
> Source: C18, 7.21.6.1/9

---

#### 2. Question

> "I would like to ask you if there is a different reason why the result of printing the `pa` through `%p` format and the result of printing `*pa` with `%p` format even the same pointer called `p`."

You only can use the former method to be proper. The latter invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) as described above.

---

#### 3. Question:

> "If I understood the above two questions, I don't need to ask about this.*why variable a is the same as the `a` printed in the `%p` format and pointer 'pa`printed in the`%p` format."

It is not the same.

Comment: I really want to say "Thanks a lot".
I understood I did something wrong by doing undefined behavior by your comment.
I was wonder 'Yeah, it is wrong to do this, but why it shows up that I didn't understood? If there's any meaning, should I know this?'
But after read your comment I accepted What I done was totally wrong thing.
Thanks so much to answering my Ques.

Answer (score 1):

1. On most real-life systems a pointer is no different to any integer, just that it holds a values presenting a memory address, rather than a value representing a number.
2. *pa is the value at where the pa pointer points, not the value of the pointer.
3. Because of the above, *pa is the same as a, they are both the value of a, not the value of the pointer.

Comment: Thanks so much to you.
I understood What I done must not be done.
So shame, I should learn basic more and more.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't say no more about all of you so kind. I was so fool, and Thanks so much.

> So It's okay I just accept **NO.1 it doesn't work normal**? Cause,
> conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.

> **No.2 result of printing '*pa' through %p means itself's address.**
>
> and result of printing **'pa' through %p** means **value of 'a'**(but I
> also got mistake that I used wrong conversion specification). If I
> want to fix it right. I should write
>
> printf("'a' someting : %p\n", a); → printf ("'a' value : %d\n", a); == 1
>
> printf("%p\n", *pa); → printf("%d\n", *pa); == 1

> **No.3**
>
> **Yeah, it may print same result.**
> ***Anyway It was wrong.***
>
> Cause I used conversion specification. So it should be change,
>
> printf("'a' something: %p\n", a); → printf ("'a' value : %d\n", a); == 1
>
> printf("%p\n", *pa); → printf("%d\n", *pa); == 1

Thanks for your teaching, and I hope what I understood must be right. Am I?