# SDL2 Pointers c and c++

Tags: c++, c, sdl-2

How it's possible that  we are storing some function in pointer's like `win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World", posX, posY, width, height, 0);` ? If it's not a function so what is it  cuz it looks like a function. Second  what type of pointer's are these  is it pointer to member  function ? I mean that  `SDL_Window *win; SDL_Renderer *renderer;`. How it's possible that I can just declare it like that without any ampersand ?
Can you text me pseudocode to understand how this pointer can hold this "function"?

```
include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int posX = 100, posY = 100, width = 320, height = 240;
    SDL_Window *win;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World", posX, posY, width, height, 0);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which language, C **or** C++?  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has smart pointers and `std::string`.  The C language doesn't.  Please update your language tags appropriately.

Comment: `SDL_CreateWindow` returns a pointer. All of the getting of the address happened inside the function. No `&` required. `&` is needed to get the address of a variable, but if that variable is already a pointer, `&` isn't needed. Unless you want to get a pointer to the pointer...

Comment: I recommend consulting an introductory text on programming C or C++. The first few chapters should be able to help you out far better than the Internet can.

Comment: `How it's possible that we are storing some function in pointer's like` [Here is a good list of C books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Please re-read the chapters related to functions. Stackoverflow is a bad place to learn programming, rather it's a place for people that already know programming that want to solve interesting problems.

Comment: A few links that provide basic discussions of pointers may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102)

Comment: @KamilCuk That's a bad list of random books, including lots of bad books... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355588/the-c-book-list-has-gone-haywire-what-to-do-with-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually win is not pointer to a function but it is a pointer to structure type  `SDL_Window`. Statement `win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World", posX, posY, width, height, 0)`  means that you have calling function `SDL_CreateWindow` with arguments `("Hello World", posX, posY, width, height, 0)` this function as the result of arguments used returns a pointer to dynamically allocated inside this function structure `SDL_Window`.

Function pointer can be declared with the following construction:

```
SDL_Window * (*functionName)(const char*, int, int, int, int, int) = SDL_CreateWindow;
```

Than used like that:

```
win = functionName("Hello World", posX, posY, width, height, 0);
```

`functionName` in this case points to `SDL_CreateWindow` function and is used to call `SDL_CreateWindow`.

Comment: OP is clearly confused by basic use of pointers. Though correct, showing a function pointer is overly confusing at this point.