# How to determine what type these variables should be (C, for CS50 "Filter" project)

Tags: c, cs50

I am a beginner to pointers and need help understanding what type I should name these variables (I don't want to make copies of them, I want to point to their memory in *image):

```
originalRed = image[j][i].rgbtRed;
originalGreen = image[j][i].rgbtGreen;
originalBlue = image[j][i].rgbtBlue;
```

From this function:

```
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            originalRed = image[j][i].rgbtRed;
            originalGreen = image[j][i].rgbtGreen;
            originalBlue = image[j][i].rgbtBlue;
            
            int sepiaRed = round(.393 * originalRed + .769 * originalGreen + .189 * originalBlue);
            int sepiaGreen = round(.349 * originalRed + .686 * originalGreen + .168 * originalBlue);
            int sepiaBlue = round(.272 * originalRed + .534 * originalGreen + .131 * originalBlue);

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

RGBTRIPLE is a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

which leads into the following 2D array which points to the memory where *image is:

```
RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
```

Comment: Actually, I think I may have figured out via the compiler that the type is supposed to be unsigned char. Still have to add one more if statement to be able to run it to check

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `BYTE` just as you have in `struct RGBTRIPLE`? Also, you can use `RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width]` as your parameter in `void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE (*image)[width])` just as you did with `calloc()`. A few links that provide basic discussions of pointers may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102) (ignore the titles, the answers have a basic pointer intro that may help)

Comment: OT: the loops should be switched. The code in the question is processing columns of the `image`. You'll get better cache performance by processing rows of the `image`.

Answer (score 2):

Just  kidding! I  figured it out on my own. The types were supposed to be:

```
unsigned char originalRed = image[j][i].rgbtRed;
unsigned char originalGreen = image[j][i].rgbtGreen;
unsigned char originalBlue = image[j][i].rgbtBlue;
```

I decided to answer instead of deleting to help anyone else. It looks like people use int as well but I was nervous that it wouldn't be enough memory. I used unsigned char because that's what the compiler said that's what type RGBTRIPLE is.

Comment: `unsigned char` is fine, but I suspect that is what `BYTE` is defined as being earlier in your code -- which would also be an option. Good job in working through the problem. (and worthy of the nod for reading and understanding your compiler output)

Comment: Aww, thank you! By the way - could I then name the variables as something like, "BYTE originalRed"? Or "RGBTRIPLE originalRed"?

Comment: The variable should be declared as `BYTE originalRed` since `image[j][i].rgbtRed` has type `BYTE`.