# free pointer by other pointer points same memory

Tags: c, pointers

Is the code down below possible?

```
int *a_p = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *b_p = a_p;
free(b_p);         //Free a_b by using b_p
a_p = b_p = NULL;
```

I'm very confused because two pointers point same memory...

If that code is impossible, could you teach me why, please?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Thank you so so so much! Appreciate you!

Comment: A few links that provide basic discussions of pointers may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102) (ignore the titles, the answers discuss pointer basics)

Comment: Some function for exemple with a void ** parameter can allocate memory you must free.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, both pointers point to the same allocated buffer, so any of them (but not both) can be used to `free()` the allocated buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is perfectly fine.

---

1. You create `a_p`, allocate a memory block, and assign the block's address to `a_p`.
   After `int *a_p = malloc(sizeof(int));`:

   ```
   int *a_p                  int @ 0x1234
   +------------+           +------------+
   | 0x1234     |           | ???        |
   +------------+           +------------+
   ```
2. You create `b_p` with the same value as `a_p`.
   After `int *b_p = a_p;`:

   ```
   int *a_p                  int @ 0x1234
   +------------+           +------------+
   | 0x1234     |           | ???        |
   +------------+           +------------+

   int *b_p
   +------------+
   | 0x1234     |
   +------------+
   ```

   Notably, this didn't allocate any memory other than `b_p` itself.
3. You free the memory block you previously allocated.
   After `free(b_p);`:

   ```
   int *a_p
   +------------+
   | 0x1234     |
   +------------+

   int *b_p
   +------------+
   | 0x1234     |
   +------------+
   ```
4. You overwrite the addresses.
   After `a_p = b_p = NULL;`:

   ```
   int *a_p
   +------------+
   | NULL       |
   +------------+

   int *b_p
   +------------+
   | NULL       |
   +------------+
   ```

The two remaining blocks (`a_p` and `b_p`) have *automatic storage duration*, so they will be automatically freed when the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are values. They can be copied via assignment.

In this example, `b_p` is set to the value of `a_p` and then `free(b_p);` is called.

At that moment, the value in `b_p` is one in `a_p`, which is a pointer returned from `malloc()` and not yet freed. Therefore, this is valid.

Another possibility is that `malloc()` failed and `NULL` is returned, but `free(NULL);` is valid and defined to do nothing, so the code is valid also in this case.