# What is the difference between these access in C?

Tags: c

i started learning C today, and i have some questions about accessing a pointer data.

I have this function in C:

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    size_t usedSize;
    char *array;
} charList;

void addToCharList(charList *list, char *data)
{
    if(list->usedSize == list->size)
    {
        list->size *= 2;
        list->array = realloc(list->array, list->size * sizeof(int));
    }
    list->array[list->usedSize++] = *data;
    printf("1: %d\n", *data);
    printf("2: %s\n", data);
    printf("3: %p\n", &data);
}
```

I use it to create a "auto growing" array of chars, it works, but i'm not understanding why i need to attribute the value "*data" to my array. I did some tests, printing the different ways i tried to access the variable "data", and i had this outputs (I tested it with the string "test"):

```
1: 116
2: test
3: 0x7fff0e0baac0
```

1: Accessing the pointer (i think it's the pointer) gives me a number, that i don't know what is.

2: Just accessing the variable gives me the actual value of the string.

3: Accessing it using the "&" gets the memory location/address.

When i'm attributing the value of my array, i can only pass the pointer, why is that? Shouldn't i be attributing the actual value? Like in the second access.

And what is this number that gives me when i access the pointer? (First access)

Comment: The 116 is the ASCII code of `t` , the character to which `data` is pointing .

Comment: Arrays cannot be passed by value in C; instead you can pass the address of where the first element of the array is found, and the recipient can then look up that address to access the array contents

Comment: You could also do `printf("1: %c\n", *data);` printing it as a character.

Comment: In `*data` the `*` is the dereference/indirection operator, so `*data` return the value to which `data` points to, but in the example `data` is a pointer that points to the first character of the string `"test"`, the character `'t'` (which is equal to the number 116 when printed as an decimal integer).

Comment: A few links that provide basic discussions of pointers may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102) (ignore the titles, the answers discuss pointer basics) Learning C isn't a race, or something you do in a semester, or year for that matter, it's more of a journey. There is a lot to learn, so slow down, pay attention to the details, and enjoy the journey.

Comment: Always `realloc()` using a temporary pointer. In the 2nd link above, see the `Location *addLocation ()` function for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in the first printf, you're not actually accessing the pointer. If you have a pointer named `myPointer`, writing `*myPointer` will actually give you access to the thing that the pointer is pointing to. It is understandable to be confused about this, as you do use the `*` operator when declaring a variable to specify that it is a pointer.

```
char* myCharPtr; // Here, the '*' means that myCharPtr is a pointer.

// Here, the '*' means that you are accessing the value that myCharPtr points to.
printf("%c\n", *myCharPtr);
```

In the second printf, you're accessing the pointer itself. And in the third printf, you're accessing a pointer *to* a char pointer. The `&` operator, when put before a variable, will return a pointer to that variable. So...

```
char myChar = 'c';

// pointerToMyChar points to myChar.
char* pointerToMyChar = &myChar;

// pointerToPointerToMyChar points to a pointer that is pointing at myChar.
char** pointerToPointerToMyChar = &pointerToMyChar;
```

When you're trying to store the value in the array, it's forcing you to do `*data` because the array stores chars, and `data` is a pointer to a char. So you need to access the char value that the pointer is pointing to. And you do that via `*data`.

Lastly: the reason that `printf("1: %d\n", *data);` prints a number is that chars are secretly (or not secretly) numbers. Every character has a corresponding numeric value, behind the scenes. You can see which numerical value corresponds to which character by looking at an [ascii table.](https://theasciicode.com.ar/)

Comment: If you're interested in this kind of thing, I'd recommend reading [Joel Spolsky's article on what every programmer should know about unicode](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)