# Differences between allocating memory spaces for a string based on the size of its characters vs. the size of the entire string

Tags: c

When we allocating memory spaces for a string, do the following 2 ways give the same result?

```
char *s = "abc";
char *st1 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(s));
char *st2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(s));
```

In other words, does allocate the memory based on the size of its characters give the same result as allocating based on the size of the whole string?

If I do use the later method, is it still possible for me to add to that memory spaces character by character such as:

```
*st = 'a';
st++;
*st = 'b';
```

or do I have to add a whole string at once now?

Comment: No. `sizeof(s)` is sizeof `a_pointer`, `strlen(s)` will be the number of characters in the string literal (`3`). You can iteratre over the generic pointer `st` as you have shown. You just keep track of the number of characters used and `realloc()` when you run out.

Comment: you should print out the values of the sizeof

Comment: `sizeof(s)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of a string.

Comment: Also don't forget to allocate for terminating null-character when you allocate for strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if we can't get you straightened out on your question and on allocating (and reallocating) storage. To begin, when you declare:

```
char *s = "abc";
```

You have declared a pointer to `char` `s` and you have assigned the starting address for the String Literal `"abc"` to the pointer `s`. Whenever you attempt to use `sizeof()` on `a_pointer`, you get `sizeof(a_pointer)` which is typically 8-bytes on x86_64 (or 4-bytes on x86, etc..)

If you take `sizeof("abc");` you are taking the size of a character array with size 4 (e.g. `{'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}`), because a string literal is an array of `char` initialized to hold the string `"abc"` (including the *nul-terminating* character). Also note, that on virtually all systems, a string literal is created in read-only memory and cannot be modified, it is immutable.

If you want to allocate storage to hold a copy of the string `"abc"`, you must allocate `strlen("abc") + 1` characters (the +1 for the *nul-terminating* character `'\0'` -- which is simply ASCII `0`, see [ASCII Table & Description](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Whenever you allocate memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed. So if you allocate for `char *st = malloc (len + 1);` characters, you do not want to iterate with the pointer `st` (e.g. no `st++`). Instead, declare a second pointer, `char *p = st;` and you are free to iterate with `p`.

Also, in C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714).

If you want to add to an allocation, you use `realloc()` which will create a new block of memory for you and copy your existing block to it. When using `realloc()`, you always reallocate using a temporary pointer (e.g. don't `st = realloc (st, new_size);`) because if when `realloc()` fails, it returns `NULL` and if you assign that to your pointer `st`, you have just lost the original pointer and created a memory leak. Instead, use a temporary pointer, e.g. `void *tmp = realloc (st, new_size);` then validate `realloc()` succeeds before assigning `st = tmp;`

Now, reading between the lines that is where you are going with your example, the following shows how that can be done, keeping track of the amount of memory `allocated` and the amount of memory `used`. Then when `used == allocated`, you reallocate more memory (and remembering to ensure you have +1 bytes available for the *nul-terminating* character.

A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define THISMANY 23

int main (void) {

    char *s = "abc", *st, *p;               /* string literal and pointer st */
    size_t  len = strlen(s),                /* length of s */
            allocated = len + 1,            /* number of bytes in new block allocated */
            used = 0;                       /* number of bytes in new block used */
    
    st = malloc (allocated);                /* allocate storage for copy of s */
    p = st;                                 /* pointer to allocate, preserve st */
    
    if (!st) {                              /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-st");
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++) {            /* copy s to new block of memory */
        *p++ = s[i];                        /* (could use strcpy) */
        used++;                             /* advance counter */
    }
    *p = 0;                                 /* nul-terminate copy */
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < THISMANY; i++) { /* loop THISMANY times */
        if (used + 1 == allocated) {        /* check if realloc needed (remember '\0') */
            /* always realloc using temporary pointer */
            void *tmp = realloc (st, 2 * allocated);    /* realloc 2X current */
            if (!tmp) {                     /* validate EVERY reallocation */
                perror ("realloc-st");
                break;                      /* don't exit, original st stil valid */
            }
            st = tmp;                       /* assign reallocated block to st */
            allocated *= 2;                 /* update allocated amount */
        }
        *p++ = 'a' + used++;                /* assign new char, increment used */
    }
    *p = 0;                                 /* nul-terminate */
    
    printf ("result st  : %s\n"             /* output final string, length, allocated */
            "length st  : %zu bytes\n"
            "final size : %zu bytes\n", st, strlen(st), allocated);
    
    free (st);      /* don't forget to free what you have allocated */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sizeofs
result st  : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
length st  : 26 bytes
final size : 32 bytes
```

Look things over and let me know if this answered your questions, and if not, leave a comment and I'm happy to help further.

If you are still shaky on what a pointer is, and would like more information, here are a few links that provide basic discussions of pointers that may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102) (ignore the titles, the answers discuss pointer basics)