# My program does not print anything and fails

Tags: c

My program does not print anything and fails.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct data{
int giorno, mese, anno;
};
struct data d, *p;

int main(void){ 

    p->giorno = 15;
    p->mese = 8;
    p->anno = 2005;
    printf("%d", p->giorno );
}
```

### OUTPUT:

Process exited after 0.2837 seconds with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue. . .

Comment: `p` is a pointer to **what**?

Comment: A few links that provide basic discussions of pointers may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102) (ignore the titles, the answers discuss pointer basics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `p` doesn't point to anywhere. The memory there is just garbage value. So, either do:

```
p = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
```

This will allocate some memory on the heap and store the address in `p`.

Or,

```
p = &<some valid memory>;
```

I think you intended to do:

```
p = &d;
```

Which would store the address of `d` in `p`.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to put data in a *struct* there isn't any need for a pointer. Just use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct data{
    int giorno, mese, anno;
};
struct data d;

int main(void){

    d.giorno = 15;
    d.mese = 8;
    d.anno = 2005;
    printf("%d", d.giorno);
}
```