# Why is my code not working, but the other one does?

Tags: c

So, I am learning how to use pointers, but although my code is almost identical to the one of the lessons I am following, I keep of getting compiling errors.

First, here is my code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void decoupeMinutes(int* heur, int* min);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int heures = 0; 
    int minutes = 90;

    decoupeMinutes(&heures, &minutes);

    printf("%d heures et %d minutes", heures, minutes);

return 0;
}

void decoupeMinutes (int* heur, int* min)
(
    *heur = *min / 60;
    *min = *min % 60;
)
```

Now, here are the errors I get when trying to compile :

> heure.c:20:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'min'; did you mean
> 'main'?
> *heur = *min / 60;
> ^~~
> main

Then :

> heure.c:20:15: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int
> (int, char **)' and 'int')
> *heur = *min / 60;
> ~~~~ ^ ~~

Also :

> heure.c:20:19: error: expected ')'
> *heur = *min / 60;
> ^

Also :

> heure.c:18:21: error: function cannot return function type 'void (int
> *)' void decoupeMinutes (int* heur, int* min)
> ^

And :

> heure.c:21:9: error: initializer element is not a compile-time
> constant
> *min = *min % 60;
> ^~~~~~~~~

Now, what I don't understant, is that the code in the lesson I am following is very similar to mine I think :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void decoupeMinutes(int* pointeurHeures, int* pointeurMinutes);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int heures = 0, minutes = 90;

    decoupeMinutes(&heures, &minutes);

    printf("%d heures et %d minutes", heures, minutes);

    return 0;
}

void decoupeMinutes(int* pointeurHeures, int* pointeurMinutes)
{
    *pointeurHeures = *pointeurMinutes / 60;
    *pointeurMinutes = *pointeurMinutes % 60; 
}
```

This last one compiles without any error.
So, what am I not seeing there ?

Comment: Maybe `min` is a macro defined somewhere in your header files. You could try to rename `min` variable to another name.

Comment: `(...)` enclosing the first function is not `{...}`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please choose a title that describes your technical problem that others might search for.

Comment: A few links that provide basic discussions of pointers may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102) (ignore the titles, the answers discuss pointer basics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `{}` instead of `()` for function body

```c
void decoupeMinutes (int* heur, int* min)
( // wrong, use {
    *heur = *min / 60;
    *min = *min % 60;
) // wrong, use }
```

Comment: I'll vote to close as typo for this reason.

Comment: Takes sharp eyes to catch the brace/paren mix up.

Comment: Damn, how did I not see it... Thank you very much sir !

Comment: Well I just copied and compiled, so yeah... Compilers do have sharp eyes :)

Comment: @Toyama70 Glad that it helped. If my answer clarified your doubt, you can mark it as accepted, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow