# Why doesn't fgets take a char pointer as the first argument?

Tags: c

Why does `fgets` segfault when I pass a `char` pointer as the first argument? For example:

```c
char *p;
fgets(p, 10, stdin); // segmentation fault
```

What's with the `char` pointer `p`, when we just declare it as `char *p` (as in the above example)?
thanks!

Comment: using the exact code as described p point to NULL and fgets() need memory to save the  10 characters

Comment: You always have to answer the question "To what valid block of memory does my pointer point?", e.g. What address does my pointer hold as its value? A few links that provide basic discussions of pointers may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102) (ignore the titles, the answers discuss pointer basics)

Comment: @pascalsautot, it doesn't point to `NULL`, it's uninitialized.

Comment: I understand why new users post answers to this. But if you are a 10k+ rep and/or C gold badge user coming across a FAQ question like this, the correct action is to open the [C tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info), scroll down to "FAQ" to find a list of canonical duplicates, then close vote for the appropriate dupe. In this case one was found below FAQ -> Pointers.

Comment: @frippe what difference do you make between uninitialiated (value is 0) and assigned by NULL (value is 0) both end up with the same problem a pointer that does not point on a memory space

Comment: @pascalsautot Uninitialized does not imply 0, it means it contains a garbage value and could point _anywhere_

Answer (score 1):

`p` contains a garbage value. You need to initialize it first.

```
char *p = (char*)malloc(10);
if (p == NULL) {
    // handle error
}
//use p

// Once you're done with p
free(p);
```

or

```
char p[10];  // Automatic storage
```

Comment: @XMan no need for "thank you comments". If you find an answer useful, then upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer `p` must point to a buffer.

```
char buf[10];
char *p = buf;
fgets(p, 10, stdin);
```

should work now. Note that array expressions decays to pointers so the code could be simpified to:

```
char p[10];
fgets(p, 10, stdin);
```

Comment: thanks, if we just declare "char *p", where the pointer p point to?

Comment: _"if we just declare "char *p", where the pointer p point to?"_: it points nowhere, it contains an undetermined value.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` can and does take a *valid* pointer to a character buffer as the first argument. In your case, your `char *p` is not valid. It has not been initialised and probably points to a junk value.

You can either initialise it to a static string or a character array which contains some sensible value.

Answer (score 0):

Here p is just a pointer and it doesn't point to anything since it has not been initialized yet. You can initialize it via allocating memory to it.

`char *p = (char*)malloc(10);`