# Does malloc() always return a character pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a book that says the following:

> The malloc() allocation still has one slight problem. We still have to
> explain the left portion of the temperature malloc(). What is the (int
> *) for?
>
> The (int *) is a typecast. You’ve seen other kinds of typecasts in this book. To convert a float >value to an int, you place (int) before the floating-point value, like this:
>
> `aVal = (int)salary;`
>
> The * inside a typecast means that the typecast is a pointer typecast.
> **malloc() always returns a character pointer.** If you want to use
> malloc() to allocate integers, floating points, or any kind of data
> other than char, you have to typecast the malloc() so that the pointer
> variable that receives the allocation (such as temps) receives the
> correct pointer data type. temps is an integer pointer; you should not
> assign temps to malloc()’s allocated memory unless you typecast
> malloc() into an integer pointer. Therefore, the left side of the
> previous malloc() simply tells malloc() that an integer pointer, not
> the default character pointer, will point to the first of the
> allocated values.

temps:

```
int * temps; /* Will point to the first heap value */
temps = (int *) malloc(10 * sizeof(int)); /* Yikes! */
```

After reading similar threads, it's said that `malloc()` returns a pointer of type void, not of type character. Am I missing something? I'm aware that it's not needed to typecast `malloc()` in C.

Comment: `malloc()`, on success, returns the beginning address to a block of memory of the size requested. On failure, `NULL` is returned. In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) Consider `int *temps; if (!(temps = malloc (10 * sizeof *temps))) { perror("malloc-temps"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }` Always **validate** EVERY allocation by checking the return.

Comment: The return is just an *Address*. So `void*` allows assignment to any type..

Comment: Your book is obsolete by about 30 years.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "The return is just an Address." Isn't it a pointer that is returned? Addresses can't be typecasted as fas as I'm concerned.

Comment: Pointers are addresses.  They can be typecast to other pointer types (with some exceptions).  They can also be typecast to `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @DanielWalker It is my understanding that pointers are variables that *hold* addresses.

Comment: That's correct.  However, it's fine to refer to a pointer as an address in the same way you refer to an `int` as an integer instead of a variable that *holds* an integer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the book?

Comment: @DanielWalker C Programming Absolute Beginner's Guide :p

Comment: @Nameless A few links that provide basic discussions of pointers may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102) (ignore the titles, the answers discuss pointer basics)  (An aside... I used to travel `Nameless` road between `I-35` and `FM 1431` going to Jonestown on Lake Travis from Dallas -- wonderful drive in the early 1980's)

Comment: You should return that book, demand your money back, it is inane garbage.  If you want to learn C, get K&R.  It is dense, but readable.   I would rather 120 pages of slow and careful reading than 700 pages of filler.

Comment: The function `void *malloc(size_t size);` returns a `void*` pointer. It is correct to say that is an address. It is a number (the address of the start of a region of memory) which can be assigned to any type of pointer variable.

Comment: The third edition of that book fro 2014 and "updated for C11" contains that text - it is incorrect - it returns a `void*`.  Moreover it is poor advice - you should specifically _not_ cast the return of `malloc()` in C. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user207421 mentioned in the comments, your book is most likely pretty old.  Originally, C didn't have a generic pointer type (i.e., `void*`).  I forget when this was added.  The closest thing back then was `char*` since every pointer, no matter its type, can be safely cast to and from a `char*` (sort of).

Comment: 3rd edition, 2014 "updated for C11" contains that text.  So not old enough to contain such an error.  `void*` at least since ANSI standardisation in 1989 (and K&R second edition), but compiler support predated that.

Answer (score 5):

Prior to the 1989 standard, C did not have a "generic" pointer type; pointer types were not compatible, so to assign a `char *` value to an `int *` variable (or vice versa) you needed to explicitly cast the value to the target type.

Also prior to the 1989 standard all the memory allocation functions (`malloc/calloc/realloc`) returned `char *`, so if you were assigning the result to a different pointer type, you had to use a cast:

```
int *ptr = (int *) malloc( some_size );
```

This, frankly, was a pain in the ass.  It was recognized that C could use some kind of a "generic" pointer type, so the `void *` type was introduced, along with the rule that `void *` values could be converted to other pointer types (and vice versa) without needing a cast.  The memory allocation functions were changed to return `void *`, so a cast is no longer necessary:

```
int *ptr = malloc( some_size );
```

You cannot dereference a `void *` - the result would be a `void` type, which has no values and no size.  For the same reason, you can’t do pointer arithmetic or use the subscript operator on a `void *`.

Answer (score 1):

> Does `malloc()` always return a character pointer?

No.  Since C89, `malloc()` returns a `void *`.