# assign value to a not initialised char* in C

Tags: c

I would like to assign a value to a not initialised char*.
The char* is global, so a char = "value" just gives me a dangling pointer.
I have seen that strncpy could be a viable option. Is it possible that the size of the char* dynamicly changes to the assigned value?
Because declaring it with a random high size does not feel right.

Thanks in advance :)

Edit 1:

```
char* charName[100];

method(anotherChar) {
strncpy(charName, anotherChar, strlen(anotherChar));
}
```

Is it possible to do this in a cleaner and safer way? It does not feel right to initalize charName with a length of 100, when the length of anotherChar is not known.

Edit 2:

```
char API_key;

void func(char* message) {
    if (waiting_for_user_input && message != NULL) {
    if (API_key == NULL) {
        API_key = (char*)malloc(strlen(message));
        strcpy(API_key, message);
    }
    else {
        API_key = (char*)realloc(API_key, strlen(message));
        strcpy(API_key, message);
    }
    waiting_for_user_input = false;
}
```

}

In this case I get warnings that "API_key" could be '0'. I do not really understand this warning, because I am checking if API_key is NULL and then handling both cases.

Comment: Is it going to change, and what values can it take on?

Comment: we need to see the relevant code

Comment: `char = "value"` no, it doesn't. If that is really from your code that pointer isn't 'dangling' regardless of global or otherwise. Literals are global constant. *Real* code describes your preponderance better than you can alone. It should be included, minimal-yet-complete, *valid*, and should amplify your concern or confusion.

Comment: @WhozCraig oh is does not? I thought so, because the global variable was not updated and set back to NULL after the method finished. Yes, i edited my question.

Comment: CodeEnjoyer, Please post a [mcve] that demos your goal and/or problem.  As is, the problem description and code do not match well.

Comment: Even if that were a proper  [mcve] (which it isn't), that first argument to `strncpy` should be puking warnings/errors from your compiler. You're sending a `char**` to a function expecting `char*`. I'm trying to understand what your actual *problem* you're trying to solve is. Are you looking to take a `char*` that is pointing to a *dynamic* string and extend (or contract) it? Change it do a different dynamic string? I see answers below that seem to guess at the problem, and provide solutions therefor. If we knew *exactly* what you're trying to do it would help immensely.

Comment: This code and its description in the text is all-over-the-scenery... Any attempt to answer this OP must make assumptions... and we all know the consequence of "assuming" something...

Comment: Might I suggest a few links that provide basic discussions of pointers that may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102) (ignore the titles, the answers discuss pointer basics)

Comment: `char* charName[100]` is any of a 100 pointers to `char` it's not compatible with the standard function `strncpy` which wants to copy a string (i.e. array of characters).

Comment: Hi, I'm voting to close because this is asking multiple questions. One about `strncpy` and another about `strcpy` and `malloc()`. I recommend deciding what you want to do any providing a mcve in a new question.

Answer (score 2):

if you are worrying about the size of `anotherChar`, simple you can can convert the code:

```
char* charName[100];

method(anotherChar) {
    strncpy(charName, anotherChar, sizeOf(anotherChar));
}
```

into :

```
char *s = NULL;
void func(char* anotherChar){
    if(s != NULL)
        free(s);

    s = (char *) malloc(strlen(anotherChar) * sizeof(char) + 1);
    strcpy(s, anotherChar);
    
}
```

so every time, we free the old memory allocated in the heap using `free(s);` and then allocate a new memory in the heap by knowing the information of `strlen(anotherChar)` which is the length of the string to be assigned till the `\0` but excluding `\0` and `sizeof(char)` which is normally **1 byte** and we add **1** to reserve a place for the null character at the end of the string.

and at last, we use `strcpy(s, anotherChar);` to copy all characters till `\0` from one string to another.

and this is some text code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *s = NULL;
void func(char* anotherChar){
    if(s != NULL)
        free(s);

    s = (char *) malloc(strlen(anotherChar) * sizeof(char) + 1);
    strcpy(s, anotherChar);

}

int main(void) {

    func("hello");
    printf("s = %s\n", s);

    func("hi");
    printf("s = %s\n", s);

    func("Dummy text");
    printf("s = %s\n", s);


  return 0;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
s = hello
s = hi
s = Dummy text
```

Comment: Notable: `sizeof(char)` is *always* `1`, and is therefore entirely optional. The only legitimate reason to include it is force-of-habit; when `malloc`ing `n` things, `n * sizeof(thing)` is the general vernacular. Also, [don't cast `malloc` in C programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Finally, if using a remotely-compliant POSIX platform, [`strdup`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) will eliminate most of the code in `func`.  `realloc` may also be incredibly helping here if used correctly.

Comment: abdo Salm, `(strlen(anotherChar) * sizeof(char) + 1)` is _conceptually_ wrong.   Should be `((strlen(anotherChar)  + 1) * sizeof(char))` - scale `strlen(anotherChar)` and `1` by `sizeof(char)`.  Yet since `char` is size 1, simplify to `(strlen(anotherChar)  + 1)`.

Comment: BTW, watch out for the coding trap with `void func(char* anotherChar){ if(s != NULL) free(s); ...`.  Consider what happens when code calls `func(s)`.

Comment: Thanks that helped. @WhozCraig i tried to implement it with realloc but i get some compiler warnings im not sure about. I am going to add it into my original question.

Answer (score 1):

After creating a char* array of a certain size, you cannot change it. These strings have a limited length and you can't expand them. But you can create a longer string and then concatenate them.

```
char* new_string = (char*) malloc((strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(new_string, a);
strcat(new_string, b);
printf("%s", new_string);
```

Sadly, the only way to do this relies on dynamic memory management or VLA which can be tricky to work with.

Comment: "After creating a char* of a certain size" is unclear.  All `char *` have the same size.   A pointer is not an array an array is not a pointer.  Perhaps you mean the array of pointers cannot change its array size?

Comment: "the only way"?  Could use variable length arrays (VLA), when supported.

Comment: As, perhaps, the OP meant, the target buffer could be defined (compile time) with a size large enough to accommodate all that will be put into it. Naturally, checking BEFORE overrunning the buffer needs to be a part of any code that writes into it. (The OP code defines an array of pointers, not bytes... I do know...)