# fgets giving me null

Tags: c, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

    int firstDigit;
    char *firstNumber = 0;

    char operator;

    int secondDigit;
    char *secondNumber = 0;
    
    printf("digit ");
    scanf("%d *[^\n]", &firstDigit);
    fgets(firstNumber, firstDigit, stdin);
    printf("%s \n", firstNumber);

}
```

The code here gives me null as firstNumber while it clearly should just be a string.

here is the results of running this code:

```
$ ./result.exe
digit 2
12
(null)
```

Comment: Where pray-tell is the storage for `firstNumber`? A few links that provide basic discussions of pointers may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102) (ignore the titles, the answers discuss pointer basics) After reading, answer the question "What valid memory does `firstNumber` point to?"

Comment: Quickfix: `char firstNumber[1024];` and validate `firstDigit <= 1024`. `scanf("%d", ...)` will suffice AND you cannot use `scanf()` correctly unless you ***check the return*** to validate all anticipated conversions succeeded.

Comment: `firstNumber` is already pointing to `NULL` even before you call `fgets`, you're invoking undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had envisioned leaving just comments, but it is clear you have a misconception about the use of `fgets()` and `scanf()`. Continuing from my comments, let's see if we can help.

First, a pointer is a normal variable that holds the *memory address* as its value. When you declare a pointer, it is uninitialized (setting the pointer `NULL` or `0` doesn't provide a valid address to anything). Before you attempt to access the memory address held by the pointer, that memory address must be a valid memory address you can read or write to.

Since you attempt to use `firstNumber` with `fgets()`, the memory address held by `firstNumber` must be the starting address for a sufficient number of characters to hold what you are reading. The easiest way to provide that is simply to declare `firstNumber` as a character-array large enough to hold the user input. (and since an array is converted to a pointer to the first element on access, you simply use the array name as your pointer)

Second, when you learn enough about how `scanf()` works to understand the pitfalls it presents to the new C programmer, you will understand it is far better to read user input with `fgets()` and then convert the input to what you need using `sscanf()` instead of `scanf()`. Any time you take user-input or attempt a numeric conversion, you cannot use either function correctly unless you ***check the return*** to determine if the input or conversion succeeded or failed.

Since you want to read a sequence of characters and then convert the input to an integer value, simply declare `firstNumber` as a character array, read the user input into the array and then attempt to convert the contents of `firstNumber` to the integer `firstDigit` (if you just want the first ASCII digit in the user-input, that is simply `firstNumber[0]`, no conversion required)

On the other hand, if you want to convert the entirety of what the user entered into an integer, just use `sscanf()` in the same manner you would use `scanf()`, except you read from the buffer `firstNumber` instead of `stdin`.

Now, understand `fgets()` reads the `'\n'` generated by the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> into the buffer it fills. While it isn't necessary to remove it for the conversion to `int`, it is often necessary if you want to use the buffer as a string and don't want any dangling `'\n'` handing off the end. Thankfully it is easy to do with `strcspn()`.

Putting it altogether to read the user-input into `firstNumber` and convert that string representation of an integer into an `int`, you could do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>   /* for strcspn() */

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main () {

    int firstDigit = 0;
    char firstNumber[MAXC];
    
    fputs ("digit: ", stdout);    /* no conversion, fputs is fine */
    
    /* use firstNumber as a temporary buffer to hold input, validate
     * fgets succeeds, otherwise user canceled with manual EOF
     * ctrl + d (or ctrl + z on windows)
     */
    if (!fgets (firstNumber, sizeof firstNumber, stdin)) {
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        return 0;
    }
    
    /* trim '\n' from end of buffer by overwriting with nul-character
     * optional -- used for outputting firstNumber as string.
     */
    firstNumber[strcspn (firstNumber, "\n")] = 0;
    
    /* now parse firstDigit from buffer with sscanf() */
    if (sscanf (firstNumber, "%d", &firstDigit) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf ("\nfirstNumber contains string: \"%s\"\n"
            "FirstDigit contains integer:  %d\n",
            firstNumber, firstDigit);
}
```

Understanding this wasn't your ultimate goal, this should provide all the basic building blocks you need to move forward reading input from the user and handling any conversions required.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/firstnumdigit
digit: 24371

firstNumber contains string: "24371"
FirstDigit contains integer:  24371
```

Or what happens if the user screws up (they will)

```
$ ./bin/firstnumdigit
digit: two hundred twenty one
error: invalid integer.
```

And handling the manual `EOF` indicating the user canceled input:

```
$ ./bin/firstnumdigit
digit: (user canceled input)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 3):

`fgets` doesn't change `firstNumber`. It can't possibly change `firstNumber` since C passes by value. So `firstNumber` still has the value you gave it, `NULL`.

What `fgets` is supposed to do is write to the memory to which `firstNumber` points. Passing `NULL` as you are doing is therefore an error. You need to pass a pointer to enough memory to hold the value you want. The second argument is the size of that memory.

Answer (score 0):

`firstNumber` is a string, but as you set it to `NULL` at its declaration `fgets` can't write anything into it. The program so comes across a segfault.

You should init `firstNumber` with `malloc`, or change its declaration to `char firstNumber[64]`

Comment: `firstNumber` is not a string, it's a pointer to `char`. A string a s \0-terminated sequence of characters, that's not the same.