# Assign characters to arrow pointer in c

Tags: c, arrow-functions

```
struct room
{
    
    char venue[15];  //variable
    
    
    
}
 *stream;
.
.
.
void idealounge(){
    int i,idealounge[10];
    
    char room1[10]="MMLC";

    ***  **  stream->venue = room1;*****
    
      
    }
```

This is a room booking system.

The name of the room called MMLC.

I expect it can store "MMLC" to stream->venue but it shows errors like "incompatible values" etc.

Comment: `stream` is an uninitialized pointer to type `struct room`; As with any pointer, if you can't answer the question "*What valid memory address does my pointer hold as its value?*", you are going to be troubled by pointers for a long time. A couple of links that provide basic discussions of pointers that may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102) (ignore the titles, the answers discuss pointer basics)

Answer (score 2):

The statement:

```
char venue[15];
```

declares `venue` to be an array of size 15 of `char`. Then,

```
char room1[10]="MMLC";
```

initialises the first 4 bytes of `room1` with the string literal `"MMLC"`, setting the rest to `\0`.

Then,

```
stream->venue = room1;
```

is invalid, because `venue` is an array, not a pointer. Arrays are not modifiable l-values. You can't assign arrays like this.

If you want to copy the contents of `room1` to the contents of `venue`, use standard `strcpy()`.

---

That being said,

```
struct room
{
    char venue[15];  //variable      
}
 *stream;
```

only allocates space for the pointer, which is uninitialized and isn't pointing to anything meaningful. So first allocate memory and initialise the pointer:¹

```
stream = malloc (sizeof (struct room));
```

Then check if it succeeded:²

```
if (!stream) {
    perror ("malloc()"); 
    /* handle error here...*/
}
```

Now perform the string copy.

---

Alternatively, you can allocate the `struct` with automatic storage duration, which is simpler and less error-prone:

```
struct room bedroom;
```

and then assign it's address to the pointer:

```
stream = &bedroom;
```

This avoids the need for dynamic memory allocation, which you might fail to `free()` later on.

---

***[1]*** — *NB that I do not cast the result of `malloc()`. `malloc()` returns a generic `void *`, or `void` pointer, which is automatically promoted to the correct type. So there's no need to cast, and doing so might hide a potential bug.*

*See also: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)*

***[2]*** — *POSIX-compliant systems set `errno` on `malloc()` failure, the above code snippet assumes it does. But you may not wish to take it for granted, and handle the error in another way.*

Answer (score 0):

```
struct room
{
    char venue[15];  //variable
}
 *stream = NULL;
 
void idealounge() {
    int i;
    int idealounge[10];
    
    char room1[10]="MMLC";
    stream = (struct room *)malloc(sizeof(struct room));
    strcpy(stream->venue, room1);
}
```

You should write this way.

Comment: Actually there's lots of variables in my struct function. Can i still let my *stream=NULL ?

Comment: yes that should be ok