# C pointer problem: Why use *c instead of c?

Tags: c

I just started learning, I didn't understand the book, so I asked for advice.
I am a beginner and don't have a good English.
Function: Combine two two-digit positive integers A and B to form an integer in C
Middle. The method of merging is: the ten digits and single digits of the A number are placed on the thousand and ten digits of the C number, and the ten and single digits of the B number are placed on the single and hundred digits of the C number.
For example: when a=45, b=12. After calling this function, c=4251.
**Here is my code**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
  
void fun(int a, int b, long *c);
 
int main()   
{ 
  int a,b;
  long c; 
  int state = 1;
  printf("Enter a: ");
  printf("(q to quit)");
 
  while( scanf("%d",&a)==state)
  {
    printf("Enter b: ");
    printf("(q to quit)");
    while( scanf("%d",&b)==state)
       {
          fun(a, b, &c);     
          printf("The result is: %ld\n", c);
 
       }
  }
  return 0;
}   
 
  void fun(int a, int b, long *c)     
{
  /**********Program**********/
    *c = 100*(a%100)+b%100;
  /**********  End  **********/
}
```

I tried removing the * and found that the result was 16. It is wrong but not know why

Comment: Imagine that you hired a house-painter to paint your house.  You give him a piece of paper (`c`) with your home address on it, and say "please paint this house green".  If he does the right thing (`*c = [...]`), he'll drive to your house and paint the house green.  If he does the wrong thing (`c = [...]`) he'll paint the piece of paper green, and when you next go to look at your house, you will find it hasn't been painted at all.

Comment: Btw the correct way to call `fun()` in your example would be `fun(a, b, &c);` ... without the `&` you are trying to pass a `long` to an argument that requires a `long *`, and that shouldn't compile.

Comment: Print out the address of `c` in `main()`, and then do the same in `fun()`. See if they both point to the same thing. Then pass a pointer to `c` as an argument to `fun()`, and print out the address contained in `c`. See if the address of `c` in `main()` and the address contained in `c` `fun()` are identical.

Comment: DO NOT suggest to the user to enter 'q' to quit when `scanf()` is expecting to see an integer value... Entering text will send the program off into space...

Comment: In the book C prime plus, I saw a similar expression like this, so I tried using it

Comment: Please do not edit the code after posting. It invalidates the existing comments and answers..

Comment: A couple of links that provide basic discussions of pointers that may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102) (ignore the titles, the answers discuss pointer basics) There is nothing magic about pointers, but when new to C, it can take looking at them from a few different angles before the light-bulb winks on. (just a normal variable that holds the memory address for something else, e.g. it points to the memory location)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about this, but I saw people say I had a mistake and then correct it

Answer (score 3):

The parameter `long *c` means `c` is an address of a variable (in this case the variable in `main()` is called `c` and you need to call the function like this `fun(a, b, &c)`).

When you want to update the *value* stored at that address `c` the syntax is `*c = ...`.  If you do `c = ...` you are updating the address of the variable which has no external effect.

Alternatively, you could change your function to return a value and the call would then look like this:

```
   c = fun(a, b);
```

and the function would be:

```
int fun(int a, int b) {
    return 100*(a%100)+b%100;
}
```