# Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?) when I try to index anything other than zero

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to edit an array (as a pointer) of structs by filling in the default values with new structs that I initialize. Doing so seems to cause some really bizarre problems. I'm learning how to use structs with pointers, so any help is appreciated.

Snippet from the main function (player just saves the startLoc without changing it)

```
Location** near;
    startLoc = initLocation("Base", 5);
    player = initPlayer(startLoc);
    near = &(startLoc->near);
    *near = initLocation("Zero", 0);
    *(near + 1) = initLocation("Two", 0);
    printf("Start near: %i\n", startLoc->nearCount);
```

Entire location.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Location {
    char isValid;
    char* name;
    struct Location* near;
    int nearCount;
} Location;

Location* initLocation(char* name, int nearCount) {
    Location* l = malloc(sizeof(Location));
    l->name = name;
    l->near = calloc(sizeof(Location) * nearCount, 1);
    l->nearCount = nearCount;
    l->isValid = 1;
    return l;
}
```

Comment: Why not using `Location* near` and then `near[0] = initLocation(...); near[1] = initLocation(...);`?

Comment: Also, `struct Location* near` is initialized to an array of `Location` objects, while function `initLocation` returns a `Location` pointer, so how can you put that pointer inside that array (i.e., set an entry in the array to the value of that pointer, or worse, think that the address of that entry would change to where that pointer is pointing to)? This isn't quite going to work.

Comment: You only allocate for one `Location` with `malloc(sizeof(Location))`. To allocate for `N` of them you would need `malloc(N * sizeof(Location))` Also, the prototype for `calloc` is `void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);`, you appear to your your `nmemb` and `size` parameters reversed.

Comment: Understand you have two options for allocation (1) allocate (and `realloc` as needed) for a collection of `struct Location`, or (2) allocate (and `realloc` as needed) a block of memory storing *pointers* to `struct Location` and then further allocate each `struct Location` and assign to your pointers in sequence. When you run out of pointers, `realloc` more and keep going. The downside to approach (2) is you must allocate both storage for pointers and storage for structs. This will add complexity over simply allocating for a collection of `struct Location` with a single allocation. Up to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with a basic discussion about a *pointer* and a *pointer-to-pointer*. A pointer is simply a variable that holds the address of something else as its value. When you declare a *pointer* to something, as you have done with your `name` or `near` members within your struct you declare a variable that will *hold the address in memory* where that type object is stored in memory (e.g. the pointer will *point* to where that object is stored)

When you declare a *pointer-to-pointer* to type (e.g. `Location **near`) you have a *pointer* that holds the address of another *pointer* as its value. That can be useful in two ways. (1) it can allow you to pass the address of a pointer as a *parameter* so that the function is able to operate on the original pointer at that address, or (2) it can allow that single pointer to point to a collection of pointers in memory, e.g.

```
 pointer
    |      pointers      allocated struct
   near --> +----+     +-------------------+
            | p1 | --> | struct Location 1 |
            +----+     +-------------------+
            | p2 | --> | struct Location 2 |
            +----+     +-------------------+
            | p3 | --> | struct Location 3 |
            +----+     +-------------------+
            | .. |     |        ...        |

    (a pointer-to-pointer to type struct Location)
```

In the second case, why choose a *pointer-to-pointer* as your type instead of just allocating for a collection of that type? Good question. There are two primary reasons, one would be if what you were allocating for can vary in size. For example:

```
 char**
    |      pointers      allocated strings
  words --> +----+     +-----+
            | p1 | --> | cat |
            +----+     +-----+--------------------------------------+
            | p2 | --> | Four score and seven years ago our fathers |
            +----+     +-------------+------------------------------+
            | p3 | --> | programming |
            +----+     +-------------------+
            | .. |     |        ...        |
```

or (2) where you want an allocated collection of an even number of objects (such as changing `char**` above to `int**`) that can be addressed using 2D-array indexing (e.g. `array[2][7]`)

Allocating for a collection of *pointers* and *objects* adds complexity because you are responsible for maintaining two allocated collections, the pointers, and the objects themselves. You must track and reallocate for both your collection of pointers (and the objects -- if needed) and then `free()` your collection of objects before freeing your allocated block of pointers.

This can be greatly simplified, if you just need some number of the same type object, such as `N - struct Location`. That gives you a single allocation, single reallocation and single free for those objects themselves (of course each object can in turn contain allocated objects as well). In your case for `near` it would be similar to:

```
 pointer
    |
   near --> +-------------------+
            | struct Location 1 |
            +-------------------+
            | struct Location 2 |
            +-------------------+
            | struct Location 3 |
            +-------------------+
            |        ...        |

       (a pointer to type struct Location)
```

In your case you are dealing with needing *nested* allocated blocks of `struct Location`. In that sense, where required, you simply need `N - struct Location` which will all be of the same size and there isn't a compelling need for 2D array indexing. From that standpoint, looking at what you are trying to do (to the best possible guess), simply allocating for blocks of `struct Location` rather than handling separate blocks of pointers pointing to individually allocated `struct Location` would seem to make much more sense.

**Implementing A Short-Example**

While there is nothing wrong with an `initLocation()` to set up a single `struct Location`, you may find it makes more sense to simply write an `addLocation()` function to add a new `struct Location` to your collection each time it is called. If you initialize your pointer to the collection `NULL` back in the caller, you can simply use `realloc()` to handle your initial allocation and subsequent reallocations.

In the following example, we just create a new `struct Location` for each name in a list and allocate for 3-`near` objects. You are free to use `addLocation()` with the `near` `struct Location` in each object just as you have with your initial collection, but that implementation is left to you as it is simply doing the same thing on a nested basis.

Putting an `addLocation()` function together in a manner that looks like what you are attempting, you could do:

```
Location *addLocation (Location *l, size_t *nmemb, char *name, int nearCount)
{
    /* realloc using temporary pointer adding 1 Location */
    void *tmp = realloc (l, (*nmemb + 1) * sizeof *l);  /* validate EVERY allocation */
    if (!tmp) {     /* on failure */
        perror ("error: realloc-l");
        return NULL;    /* original data good, that's why you realloc to a tmp */
    }

    /* on successful allocation */
    l = tmp;                                /* assign reallocated block to l */
    l[*nmemb].isValid = 1;                  /* assign remaining values and */
    l[*nmemb].name = name;                  /* allocate for near */
    l[*nmemb].near = calloc(nearCount, sizeof(Location));
    if (!l[*nmemb].near) {
        perror ("calloc-l[*nmemb].near");
        return NULL;
    }
    l[*nmemb].nearCount = nearCount;        /* set nearCount */
    (*nmemb)++;                             /* increment nmemb */

    return l;  /* return pointer to allocated block of Location */
}
```

You could then loop filling each with something similar to:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nmemb;)  /* loop adding 1st nmemb names */
        if (!(l = addLocation (l, &i, names[i], nearCount)))
            break;
```

(**note:** `i` is being updated in `addLocation` so there is no need for `i++` in your loop definition)

A complete example could be written as follows. I have added a print function and a function to delete all allocated memory as well. In the call to `addLocation` below, you will see `names[i%nnames]` used instead of `names[i]` and using the counter *modulo* the total number of names in my list just ensures that a name from the list is provided, no matter how big `i` gets.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct Location {
    char isValid;
    char *name;
    struct Location *near;
    int nearCount;
} Location;

Location *addLocation (Location *l, size_t *nmemb, char *name, int nearCount)
{
    /* realloc using temporary pointer adding 1 Location */
    void *tmp = realloc (l, (*nmemb + 1) * sizeof *l);  /* validate EVERY allocation */
    if (!tmp) {     /* on failure */
        perror ("error: realloc-l");
        return NULL;    /* original data good, that's why you realloc to a tmp */
    }

    /* on successful allocation */
    l = tmp;                                /* assign reallocated block to l */
    l[*nmemb].isValid = 1;                  /* assign remaining values and */
    l[*nmemb].name = name;                  /* allocate for near */
    l[*nmemb].near = calloc(nearCount, sizeof(Location));
    if (!l[*nmemb].near) {
        perror ("calloc-l[*nmemb].near");
        return NULL;
    }
    l[*nmemb].nearCount = nearCount;        /* set nearCount */
    (*nmemb)++;                             /* increment nmemb */

    return l;  /* return pointer to allocated block of Location */
}

void prn_locations (Location *l, size_t nmemb)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nmemb; i++)
        if (l[i].isValid)
            printf ("%-12s    nearCount: %d\n", l[i].name, l[i].nearCount);
}

void del_all (Location *l, size_t nmemb)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nmemb; i++)
        free (l[i].near);   /* free each structs allocated near member */

    free (l);   /* free all struct */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *endptr,   /* use with strtoul conversion, names below */
        *names[] = { "Mary", "Sarah", "Tom", "Jerry", "Clay", "Bruce" };
    size_t  nmemb = argc > 1 ? strtoul (argv[1], &endptr, 0) : 4,
            nnames = sizeof names / sizeof *names;
    int nearCount = 3;      /* set nearCourt */
    Location *l = NULL;     /* pointer to allocated object */

    if (errno || (nmemb == 0 && endptr == argv[1])) {   /* validate converstion */
        fputs ("error: nmemb conversion failed.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nmemb;)  /* loop adding 1st nmemb names */
        if (!(l = addLocation (l, &i, names[i%nnames], nearCount)))
            break;

    prn_locations (l, nmemb);
    del_all (l, nmemb);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/locationalloc
Mary            nearCount: 3
Sarah           nearCount: 3
Tom             nearCount: 3
Jerry           nearCount: 3
```

Or, for example if you wanted to allocate for `10` of them, then:

```
$ ./bin/locationalloc 10
Mary            nearCount: 3
Sarah           nearCount: 3
Tom             nearCount: 3
Jerry           nearCount: 3
Clay            nearCount: 3
Bruce           nearCount: 3
Mary            nearCount: 3
Sarah           nearCount: 3
Tom             nearCount: 3
Jerry           nearCount: 3
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/locationalloc
==13644== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13644== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13644== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13644== Command: ./bin/locationalloc
==13644==
Mary            nearCount: 3
Sarah           nearCount: 3
Tom             nearCount: 3
Jerry           nearCount: 3
==13644==
==13644== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13644==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13644==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 1,728 bytes allocated
==13644==
==13644== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==13644==
==13644== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13644== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Let me know if this comports with your intent and whether you have any additional questions.

Comment: Would you happen to know of the best free equivalent to valgrind that can be ran in Windows 10 command line? I can't use Microsoft's solution because I'm just using Atom as my editor, and the other ones I've found either require a license or are meant for determining which program is causing problems rather than giving more information.
I'm also going to use this comment to say that even though my final solution vastly differed from yours (it's for a school project so, y'know, plagiarism and whatnot), you helped me greatly in seeing where I went so horribly wrong.

Comment: Sure, see [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

Comment: I actually found that post in my initial search, but Insure++ does cost money and the link for Purify just sends me to IBM's base software page. I can't find any link to Purify, even after checking the search function for it. Maybe I'm just not seeing something obvious :P

Comment: [PurifyPlus](https://www.teamblue.unicomsi.com/products/purifyplus/)